# Conseguir valor de un select con angular y reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Tengo este select pero no soy capaz de obtener el valor seleccionado:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                                    <label>Modelo</label>                                       
                                    <select formControlName="model_vehicle" name="model_vehicle" (change)="cambiaDatos()" class="selectpicker form-control bs-select-hidden" data-live-search="true" dropdown>
                                            <option *ngFor="let menu of this._menu.menuesModel" value="1">{{menu.model}}</option>                               
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

la funcion que debe invocar es:

```
cambiaDatos() {
let v = $('.selectpicker').val();
console.log(v);
```

aclaro que si les quito las clases que tiene el select si me funciona, pero quiero poder usarlas tambien. alguna sugerencia?

Comment: y donde asignas el model del input?

Comment: this.addform =   new FormGroup({       
    model_vehicle:  new FormControl('')       
  });